# Cannot use legacy factories in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, factory, laravel-8

I am upgrading my laravel 7.x project to 8.

I am sticking with the legacy factories for now as I have lots of them and have them in use in tests and things so would take forever to swap out to the new class structure.

The problem is I seem unable to be able to run my seeders or tests locally (which have legacy factories).

I have imported the new `laravel/legacy-factories` and set the namespaces on my seeders and updated the composer.json file.  But every time I try and run a seeder or test I get an error

```
Unable to locate factory for [App\Models\User] (or any other model)
```

I removed the `classmap` from the `composer.json` as the docs suggest but tried it with and without that in place.

Ive tried completely deleting all the caches and running `composer install` with no joy.

Anyone else had this problem?

UPDATE - Here is my composer.json file. Some of the lines have been removed.

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.4",
        "bacon/bacon-qr-code": "^2.0.2",
        "browner12/helpers": "^3.2",
        "dg/mysql-dump": "^1.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.11",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.9",
        "graham-campbell/github": "^9.4.0",
        "graylog2/gelf-php": "^1.6",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5.5",
        "jeremykendall/php-domain-parser": "^5.7",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
        "laravel/helpers": "^1.3",
        "laravel/legacy-factories": "^1.0",
        "laravel/scout": "^8.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.4",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.0",
        "league/csv": "^9.6",
        "mandrill/mandrill": "^1.0",
        "mariuzzo/laravel-js-localization": "^1.7",
        "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^2.0.1",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "^2.0.29",
        "pragmarx/google2fa": "^8.0",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "segmentio/analytics-php": "^1.5",
        "spatie/fractalistic": "^2.9",
        "zachleigh/laravel-property-bag": "^1.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "laravel/dusk": "^6.8",
        "mockery/mockery": "1.4.2",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0",
        "filp/whoops": "~2.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
        // also tried with the classmap here
        "psr-4": {
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/",
            // Also tried with the factories namespace here
        },
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
                "laravel/dusk"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `composer.json`?

Comment: @Jerodev added as requested.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve this in the end by simply deleting the `packages.php` and `services.php` files from the bootstrap directory and then `composer dump-autoload` did the trick.